# Run time error while exporting TDMS file into excel using tdmsAddIn.Connect addin in the VBA code

Tags: excel, vba

I have been trying to export NI TDMS files into my workbook and found a vba code posted by James Humphrey which is exactly what I am looking for. The issue is that whenever I try to run the code, it gives me a run time error which basically says that only the admin can execute the code.

Attached is snippet of the error and the code I used from James Humphrey's post.

[image]

Since I am not the admin, does anyone have a workaround for this issue? Thanks.

```
Sub ConvertTDMStoCSV()
'
' ConvertTDMS Macro
'
' Acts upon all .tdms files in a "source" directory,
' loading each one using the ExcelTDM Add In,
' deleting the first sheet and saving the
' remaining stream data as one .csv file
' in a "target" directory.  Writes a list of
' the files converted in a new sheet.
'
Dim sourceDir As String, targetDir As String, fn As String, fnBase As String
Dim fso As Object, n As Long, resp As Integer, strNow As String, newSheet As Object
Dim tdmsAddIn As COMAddIn, importedWorkbook As Object
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set tdmsAddIn = Application.COMAddIns.Item("ExcelTDM.TDMAddin")
tdmsAddIn.Connect = True
Call tdmsAddIn.Object.Config.RootProperties.DeselectAll
Call tdmsAddIn.Object.Config.ChannelProperties.DeselectAll
tdmsAddIn.Object.Config.RootProperties.SelectCustomProperties = False
tdmsAddIn.Object.Config.GroupProperties.SelectCustomProperties = False
tdmsAddIn.Object.Config.ChannelProperties.SelectCustomProperties = False


'Choose TDMS Source Directory
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    .Title = "Choose Source Directory of TDMS Files"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .InitialFileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"
    .Show
    On Error Resume Next
    sourceDir = .SelectedItems(1)
    Err.Clear
    On Error GoTo 0
End With
If Dir(sourceDir, vbDirectory) = "" Then
    MsgBox "No such folder.", vbCritical, sourceDir
    Exit Sub
End If

'Choose CSV Target Directory
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    .Title = "Choose Target Directory for CSV Files"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .InitialFileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"
    .Show
    On Error Resume Next
    targetDir = .SelectedItems(1)
    Err.Clear
    On Error GoTo 0
End With
If Dir(targetDir, vbDirectory) = "" Then
    MsgBox "No such folder.", vbCritical, targetDir
    Exit Sub
End If



fn = Dir(sourceDir & "\*.tdms")
If fn = "" Then
    MsgBox "No source TDMS files found.", vbInformation
    Exit Sub
End If

resp = MsgBox("Begin conversion of TDMS files?" & vbCrLf & sourceDir & vbCrLf & "to" & vbCrLf & targetDir, vbYesNo, "Confirmation")
If resp = vbNo Then
    MsgBox "Execution cancelled by user."
    Exit Sub
End If

Set newSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count))
strNow = WorksheetFunction.Text(Now(), "m-d-yyyy h_mm_ss")
newSheet.Name = strNow
newSheet.Cells(1, 1).Value = "Files converted on " & strNow
newSheet.Cells(2, 1).Value = "TDMS Source Directory: " & sourceDir
newSheet.Cells(3, 1).Value = "CSV Target Directory: " & targetDir


Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
n = 5
Do While fn <> ""
    fnBase = fso.GetBaseName(fn)

    On Error Resume Next
    Call tdmsAddIn.Object.ImportFile(sourceDir & "\" & fn, True)
    If Err Then
        MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Set importedWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    importedWorkbook.Sheets(1).Delete
    importedWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=targetDir & "\" & fnBase & ".csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV
    importedWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    newSheet.Cells(n, 1).Value = fnBase
    n = n + 1
    fn = Dir
Loop
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True


Set fso = Nothing
Set newSheet = Nothing
Set importedWorkbook = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Please include the error as *text* in the quesion, not as an image. Also: which line of code is triggering the error?

Comment: Run-Time error '-2147467259 (80004005)':
This add-in is installed for all users on this computer and can only be connected or disconnected by an administrator.

And it happens in the below line(7th line of the actual code, excluding comment line while counting):

tdmsAddIn.Connect=True

Comment: If the add-in is already installed/connected, that line of code may not be necessary. Try commenting it out and see what happens...

Comment: Yup. That did the trick. Thanks so much.

Comment: After exporting my tdms to excel using the addin, the csv gets segmented to multiple sheets. But the code here deletes the first sheet and saves the content of the 2nd sheet(which becomes the first sheet actually). How can I save all the sheets from the generated tdms to csv file?